# Strange error with underscore in Alamofire parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to pass username, password and grant_type values as a POST request.

Currently I have an array set up like :

```
params = [
 "grant_type": "password",
 "password": password,
 "username": user
]
```

When they get passed to my alamofire POST request though, and I log them out they look like this:

```
params = {
"grant_type" = password;
password = pas;
username = user;
}
```

With `pas` and `user` being my inputted values.

This results in a 400 error from my server, I suspect its because `grant_type` is being read as having quotes for some reason?

This is how im making my POST request:

```
networking.makePostRequest(Constants.loginUrl, params: loginParams) { response, json in
        print("response")
        print(response)
        print("json")
        print(json)

    }
```

With the actual POST request function looking like this:

```
unc makePostRequest(url : String, params : AnyObject, completionHandler: (httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse, responseObject:JSON?) -> ())  -> Request? {


    print("params = \(params)")
    return Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)


        .responseJSON { _, response, result in completionHandler(

            httpResponse: response!,
            responseObject:
            {
                var json: JSON?

                switch result {
                case .Success:



                    if let data: AnyObject = result.data
                    {

                        json = JSON(data)
                    }

                    return json

                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    print(error)
                }

                 return json

                }()
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: We need some code...

Comment: thanks, ive updated my question

Comment: what is your exact loginParams ?

Comment: the ones im trying to use or the ones that get POSTed?